# NSImageCell rotation animation

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, animation, core-animation, nsimagecell

I need to animate an NSImageCell on an NSOutlineView. I want it to look as the Sync Icon next to the device on iTunes.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i just spent like 30 minutes researching this :-). The best way to do this is with an NSImageView, because you can just call +setFrameCenterRotation:(float) with the animator like so.

```
    NSImageView *v = [whatever];
    [[v animator] setFrameCenterRotation:(float)whateverYouWant];
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this and let know how it went.

Comment: Be careful, your view needs to be layer-backed for this to work.